# Remove all styles from dynamic label in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a label and I got some text from database.
text format like: Windows Server 2008 ...etc
But sometimes there are different fonts or something like style. How can I remove all of them quickly?

I know I can make it with replace command. But is there any quick way for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that you can use control_name.attribute.remove in asp.net.